# Как сгенерировать самоподписанный сертификат для tomcat8?

Tags: linux, unix, tomcat, ssl

генерирую сертификат по мануалу
http://tecadmin.net/configure-ssl-certificate-in-tomcat/

пункт 2 пропускаю как там и написано

страница по адресу https://localhost:8443/ не загружается

Comment: То есть, процесс создания сертификата, подписанного доверенным центром сертификации, вы пропустили и в результате не было создано никакого сертификата.

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария:

---

То есть, процесс создания сертификата, подписанного доверенным центром сертификации, вы пропустили, и в результате не было создано никакого сертификата.